# Happy numbers - recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have an issue with a recursive algorithm, that solves the problem of finding the happy numbers.

Here is the code:

```
function TestingFunction(number){
  sumNumberContainer = new Array(0);
  CheckIfNumberIsHappy(number);
}
function CheckIfNumberIsHappy(number){
  var sumOfTheNumbers = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
    sumOfTheNumbers += Math.pow(parseInt(number[i]), 2);
  }
  console.log(sumOfTheNumbers);
  if(sumOfTheNumbers == 1){
    return CheckIfNumberIsHappy(sumOfTheNumbers.toString());
    //return true;
  } else {
    sumNumberContainer.push(sumOfTheNumbers);
    if(sumNumberContainer.length > 1){
      for (var i = 0; i < sumNumberContainer.length - 1; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < sumNumberContainer.length; j++) {
          if(sumNumberContainer[i] == sumNumberContainer[j]){
            return CheckIfNumberIsHappy(sumOfTheNumbers.toString());
            //return false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    CheckIfNumberIsHappy(sumOfTheNumbers.toString());
  }
}
```

Algorithm is working ALMOST fine. I've tested it out by calling function with different numbers, and console was displaying correct results. The problem is that I almost can't get any value from the function. There are only few cases in which I can get any value: If the number is build out of ,,0", and ,,1", for example 1000.
Because of that, I figured out, that I have problem with returning any value when the function is calling itself again.

Now I ended up with 2 results:

- Returning the

  ```
  return CheckIfNumberIsHappy(sumOfTheNumbers.toString());
  ```

  which is giving an infinity looped number. For example when the number is happy, the function is printing in the console number one again and again...
- Returning the

  ```
  //return true
  ```

  or

  ```
  //return false
  ```

  which gives me an undefined value

I'm a little bit in check by this problem, and I'm begging you guys for help.

Comment: what is a happy number

Comment: Ymm, my english is not that good to explain that in words, so I'll do that using example. We are taking the number 7. First we are squaring the number, so: 7^2 = 49. Next step is taking each cipher included in that number, and add square of them, so: 4^2 + 9^2 = 16 + 81 = 97. And we are doing this while the result is equal to 1 or the number repeated itself throught the recursive process.

Comment: @Vorbert Your code seems overly complicated for what the problem is. Maybe share your process steps instead ? Also, this can be done with a a while loop too.

Comment: Yea I know. That was a school exercises, and my teacher show me pretty simple solution with the modulo and a few line of the code. But you know ... I wrote something and it ALMOST worked fine, so I have to make this work, because I want to be a better programmer. I don't want to give up on that ,,project"

Comment: @Vorbert sometimes an approach you choose has a flaw that just can't be fixed. In that case it's fine to delete all code, write down the process steps you need to take, and then re-program. Just FYI, don't fixate, hope you get this working.

Comment: @Giannis The steps are following: Im taking the number in string, For each cipher in the number I'm squaring and adding it to the rest of the cipher, the variable ,,sumOfTheNumbers" is storing the result. Next I'm checking if the number is equal 1, if so, then I want to return value of true, cause It's happy number. If no, then I want to look in previous attempts in case that the sum of the numbers repeated itself. If so, then I want to return false value, because the number is sad. If none of those cases were true, then I want to call my function again, until I get the result.

Comment: @Giannis I started to think the same, that's why I used the last resort option which is this website.

Comment: @Vorbert: Your code is almost correct. Restore the `return true/false;` (to stop recursion) and add `return` to your recursive call of `CheckIfNumberIsHappy`.

Comment: @RaphaMex It's still returning an undefined ;/

Comment: @Vorbert: I put it in an answer. It works! :-)

Comment: @RaphaMex Now It is working in my code too, I just had to return the given value by the testFunction. User: Mark_M told me that, and that was a main problem with the returning result. But thanks a lot, cause that information helped me too! c:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the solution, which was given to me in the comments, by the user: Mark_M.

I just had to use my previous

```
return true / return false
```

also I had to return the recursive statement in the function, and return the value of the CheckIfTheNumberIsHappy function, which was called in TestingFunction.

The working code:

```
function TestingFunction(number){
  sumNumberContainer = new Array(0);
  return CheckIfNumberIsHappy(number);
}
function CheckIfNumberIsHappy(number){
  var sumOfTheNumbers = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
    sumOfTheNumbers += Math.pow(parseInt(number[i]), 2);
  }
  console.log(sumOfTheNumbers);
  if(sumOfTheNumbers == 1){
    return true;
  } else {
    sumNumberContainer.push(sumOfTheNumbers);
    if(sumNumberContainer.length > 1){
      for (var i = 0; i < sumNumberContainer.length - 1; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < sumNumberContainer.length; j++) {
          if(sumNumberContainer[i] == sumNumberContainer[j]){
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return CheckIfNumberIsHappy(sumOfTheNumbers.toString());
  }
}
```

Thanks for the great support :)

Answer (score 1):

I would take a step back and reexamine your problem with recursion in mind. The first thing you should think about with recursion is your edge cases — when can you just return a value without recursing. For happy numbers, that's the easy case where the sum of squares === 1 and the harder case where there's a cycle. So test for those and return appropriately. Only after that do you need to recurse. It can then be pretty simple:

```js
function sumSq(num) {
  /* simple helper for sums of squares */
  return num.toString().split('').reduce((a, c) => c * c + a, 0)
}

function isHappy(n, seen = []) {
  /* seen array keeps track of previous values so we can detect cycle */
  let ss = sumSq(n)
  
  // two edge cases --  just return
  if (ss === 1) return true
  if (seen.includes(ss)) return false
  
  // not an edge case, save the value to seen, and recurse.
  seen.push(ss)
  return isHappy(ss, seen)
}

console.log(isHappy(23))
console.log(isHappy(22))
console.log(isHappy(7839))
```

Comment: Oh, so the recursive option should be the case if the number takes cycle to calcule, else it should make a simple verification if the number is already happy. Thanks for that advice!

Comment: The recursive option is only for cases that are not 1 or the sum or squares has not been seen (i.e. not in seen).

Comment: Ikr, and I thought that I put those cases correctly in my algorithm, because first Im checking those scenarios, and if they are not true, then I'm calling the function again.

Comment: @Vorbert I see the checks in your algorithm, but you are recursing again when those checks are true — you should just return true of false (like in your comments). And you need a way to remember from one pass to another the numbers you've seen, which is why this passes the array with each recursion.

Comment: Oh, so the good option would be like to add a boolean to the funtion parameters, which defines if the recursion should be stopped?

Comment: @Vorbert I think your code actually works if bring back the`return true` and `return false` for your edge cases  and also `return CheckIfNumberIsHappy(sumOfTheNumbers.toString());` at the end.

Comment: somebody just mentioned about that, and when I modify my code, the result is always: undefined ;/

Comment: @Vorbert You need to return from `TestingFunction()` too.

Comment: Ouuuugh, that solved the problem! I didn't know that I have to return the value from the calling function ... but now I know! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified approach to the problem

```js
const digits = x =>
  x < 10
    ? [ x ]
    : [ ...digits (x / 10 >> 0), x % 10 ]

const sumSquares = xs =>
  xs.reduce ((acc, x) => acc + x * x, 0)
  
const isHappy = (x, seen = new Set) =>
  x === 1
    ? true
    : seen.has (x)
      ? false
      : isHappy ( sumSquares (digits (x))
                , seen.add (x)
                )
    
for (let n = 1; n < 100; n = n + 1)
  if (isHappy (n))
    console.log ("happy", n)
    
// happy 1
// happy 7
// happy 10
// ...
// happy 97
```

The program above could be improved by using a technique called [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)

Comment: I'm curious, what would you memoize here?

Comment: If `isHappy (x)` yields a sequence of `x`->`y`->`z` and then at a later time, we ask `isHappy (y)` or `isHappy (z)`, we already know the answer because it was determined by `x`. To be clear, memoization *only* helps if we need to determine the happiness of a collection of numbers. The more numbers we have, the more time we save.

Comment: I mentioned about that kind of method in the comments under my question. I know that is more simplier and ,,more correct" way, and I'll be  forced to reprogram my algorithm in similar way, but I wanted to check if there is anything I can do with my piece of code, to make it work correctly. But anyway, thanks for the advice!

Comment: Ah, thanks @user633183 -- I was looking for a way to use it in a single test and it didn't make sense to me.

Comment: Nice piece of code. I think OP wants to understand his error though.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct. You just forgot to return the result of the recursive call:

```
function TestingFunction(number){
    sumNumberContainer = new Array(0);
    if (CheckIfNumberIsHappy(number))
        console.log(number);
}
function CheckIfNumberIsHappy(number){
    var sumOfTheNumbers = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
        sumOfTheNumbers += Math.pow(parseInt(number[i]), 2);
    }
    if(sumOfTheNumbers == 1){
        return true;
    } else {
        sumNumberContainer.push(sumOfTheNumbers);
        if(sumNumberContainer.length > 1){
            for (var i = 0; i < sumNumberContainer.length - 1; i++) {
                for (var j = i + 1; j < sumNumberContainer.length; j++) {
                    if(sumNumberContainer[i] == sumNumberContainer[j]){
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return CheckIfNumberIsHappy(sumOfTheNumbers.toString());
    }
}

for (let i=0; i<100; ++i)
    TestingFunction(i.toString()); // 1 7 10 13 ... 91 94 97
```